# How to locate a not stable table element using Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, html-table

Here is the HTML:

```
<table class="wikitable openei-infobox">

    <tbody><tr>
    <th> <a href="/wiki/Property:Name" title="Property:Name">Name</a>
    </th>
    <td> Ambit Energy, L.P.
    <pre style="display: none;"></pre>
    </td></tr>
    <tr>
    <th> <a href="/wiki/Property:Place" title="Property:Place">Place</a>
    </th>
    <td> <a href="/wiki/Maryland" title="Maryland">Maryland</a>
    <pre style="display: none;"></pre>
    ......
```

I need to locate the element **Maryland** using Selenium, but I cannot use xpath as following `("//a[@href='...']")` and I cannot use `By.linkText` either, because it is not stable. I tried the following:

```
String el = driver.findElement(By.xpath(("//table[@class='wikitable openei-infobox']/td[1]"))).get(1).getText();
        System.out.println(el);
```

What is wrong in my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:
String el = driver.findElement(By.xpath(("//tr[2]/td[1]"))).getText();
        System.out.println(el);